# Can I simplify and negate this? ^(//|//\s+|\s+//|\s+//\s+)

Tags: script, regex, shell-script, perl

Basically I want to match commented lines like:

```
// foobar (this is a commented line)
```

but I want to make sure I catch this line even if there is white space either side of the comment signature '//' in this case.

```
^(//|//\s+|\s+//|\s+//\s+)\bfoobar.*$
```

I managed to simplify it down to: `^(\s*//\s*)\bfoobar.*$`

**Negation: Here I need your help.**

I tried this: `^(?!(\s*\/{2}\s*)\bfoobar.*$).*$`, but it matches all lines except the ones that start with a comment.

I need only the lines which have foobar but are uncommented!

Comment: (1) Yeah, (0  OR  (1 or more)) clearly simplifies to (0 or more), so ``//|//\s+`` simplifies to ``//\s*``. Likewise for the spaces before the `//`.  (2) If you’re not doing a capture group, you don’t need the parentheses.  (3) You don’t need the `\b`.  (4) If you don’t care what come after the `foobar`, just leave off the `.*$`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Any ideas how to do the negation?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1449270/edit) and add some lines that must match and some that mustn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `^(?!\h*//)\h*foobar\b` or `^(?!\h*//).*\bfoobar\b` if there are some characters before `foobar`

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?!           # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't 
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    //          # 2 slashes
  )             # end lookahead
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  foobar        # literally "foobar"
  \b            # word boundary, to not match "foobarbar"
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    say "Match: $_" if m~^(?!\h*//)\h*foobar\b~;
}

__DATA__
// foobar (this is a commented line)
// foofoo (this is a commented line)
foobar (this is an uncommented line)
```

**Output:**

```
Match: foobar (this is an uncommented line)
```